# Tabela com espaçamento em resoluções mobile/tablet

Tags: html, tabela-html

Desenvolvendo um email marketing, me deparei com espaçamentos (de aproximadamente 1px) que aparecem entre as colunas porém esse espaçamento só aparece em resoluções menores de 980px.

O código foi gerado através do software Fireworks e teve algumas modifcações feitas por mim após.

Já utilizei diversas técnicas como remover borda, padding e spacing da tabela porém mesmo assim não funcionou.

Segue imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código: https://guitarcamera.com/email-marketing/watch-demo/watch-demo.html

Comment: Tente dar um display: block; na imagem

Comment: @caiocafardo Boa tarde. Já existe uma regra para dar display:block em todas as imagens.

Comment: Mas esse erro que viu foi depois que enviou por e-mail? Pois em muitos casos, o leitor de e-mail lê apenas css inline.

Comment: @caiocafardo Percebi inicialmente esse erro após ter enviado o email e aberto ele no celular. Depois disso verifquei que no navegador, abaixo de 980px, também acontecia isso. Em resoluções maiores isso não acontece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de bastante pesquisa descobri que o termo para esse problema é "hairline".

É um comportamento padrão que ocorre na maiora dos dispositivos mobile. Não há um método de resolve-lo, apenas é possíve disfarça-lo colocando o background ou bordas com a cor predominante ou de fundo (geralmente branco).

A dica para quem estiver passando por isso é evitar criar email marketing que seja necessário criar recortes em imagens.

Segue a fonte: https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5230-hairline-lines-around-images-in-tables